# npm-scripts: prepare versus prepublish for installing TypeScript projects from Git URL

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-scripts

I'm confused by the documentation for [`npm-scripts`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) as it relates to the `prepare` and `prepublish` steps and which one is best for a package that is installed from Git/GitHub.

Specifically, we have two TypeScript projects:

Project A depends on Project B.

Project A specifies the dependency as a Git URL in its `package.json`, for example:

```
"dependencies": {
  "project-b": "git+ssh://git@<path to project b>.git",
  ...
}
```

Now, running `npm install` from the project root of Project A will essentially download the un-transpiled version of Project B.

**We want `tsc` for Project B to be run as part of `npm install` when `npm install` is run from the root of Project A.  What is the best script step to do this?**

The NPM docs seem to give conflicting guidance between `prepare` and `prepublish`:

- `prepare`: "Run ... when installing git dependencies."
- `prepublish`: "use a prepublish script. This includes tasks such as ... Compiling CoffeeScript source code into JavaScript." ([source](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#use-cases))

So, which one is it?

Comment: Some fun reading: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10074

Comment: ...Actually, looks like `prepare` did have the desired effect, though the resulting JS was put in `dist/` (as to be expected; I just neglected to look there).

Comment: Hi, I have found that prepare is supposed to the right script for this, but it doesn't get triggered.